# conditional redirect of webpage based on a visitor's IP (.edu, .gov, etc)

Tags: php, .htaccess, html

I would like to do the following:

if a user comes from .edu, .gov and .com. then the user will be redirected to page A.

otherwise, the user will be redirected to page B.

Please advise how to proceed. Thank you very much.